# How can I resolve an issue installing numpy and other packages on a new Mac?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, apple-silicon

I installed the universal2 installation of python 3.9.1 from python.org, and the latest version of pip. I am running into an issue where if I try to install common packages (like numpy or pandas) I get an error message stating "ERROR: Could not build wheels for bumpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly". Is there any workaround? Surely there is a way to install a common package like numpy to run on Apple Silicon. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This often indicates that you have out-of-date packages. Do these upgrades:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

and then try again.